# WooCommerce show out of stock products SELECTIVELY

Tags: php, woocommerce

How can I selectively show out of stock products in a category view? I know I can do it in the WooCommerce options panel for all products but I need to control this more. I'm thinking along the lines of adding something into the functions.php of my theme such as:

```html
add_action( 'xyz', function() {
    global $product;

    if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        //Need to make it viewable here but selectively, not globally;
    }
});
```

A single checkbox toggle on the product page would be perfect, eg "Show even if stock level is zero".

Note - With > 500 products, I need to have a checkbox for those few that I need visible, not the other way round.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Well that was a heck of a lot trickier than I thought it was going to be. The solution comes in three parts.

First, you must add a checkbox to the admin product metabox. I thought it would be appropriate if we placed it near the stock status inputs.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_stock_status', 'so_27971630_hide_if_out_of_stock' );

function so_27971630_hide_if_out_of_stock(){
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 'id' => '_hide_if_out_of_stock', 'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple show_if_variable', 'label' => __( 'Hide this product from archives when out of stock?', 'your-plugin-domain' ) ) );
}
```

Then we need to save this data. Normally, I'd save a checkbox as 'yes' versus 'no' like WooCommerce does. However, getting the product query correct, required that the meta exist when you wanted to hide the item and not exist at all otherwise... hence the if/else `update_post_meta()` versus `delete_post_meta()`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'so_27971630_save_product_meta' );

function so_27971630_save_product_meta( $post_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['_hide_if_out_of_stock'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hide_if_out_of_stock', 'yes' );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_hide_if_out_of_stock' );
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to tweak the product query. WooCommerce builds a custom query for products in its `WC_Query` class. Basically what I've done is in the case where you aren't mass hiding all out of stock items via the plugin option, this code will modify the meta query so that any item that does not have the meta key `_hide_if_out_of_stock` will be shown. That is a counter-intuitive way of sayingn that any product where the box "hide when out of stock" is checked will be hidden.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'so_27971630_product_query' );

function so_27971630_product_query( $q ){

    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) == 'no' ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'       => '_hide_if_out_of_stock',
                    'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
                );
    }

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I'll have a look at implementing this as soon as I can and let you know.

Comment: I actually tested this one, so I think it should work. Let me know.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work unless the stock quantity was also set to 1. Since the system auto decrements the stock by 1 when a sale takes place I would like to show the correct stock level as zero but still optionally display my product, ideally listing it as 'Sold', on the product-category page.

Comment: I just found out that when stock is set to 1 the 'In Stock' also turns on automatically, hence why it displayed. Also, I would prefer the checkbox off by default and then 'Show, even when out of stock' to be the option.

Comment: Well the reason I didn't do it that way is that by default the WooCommerce product query uses the `AND` relation for the meta queries. So the item must meet the `_visibility` and the `_stock_status`.. so when we throw in a `_show_if_out_of_stock` meta field = 'yes' (or exists) there is no way a product can meet all three and so no products match at all.

Comment: I looked at this again and I still can't get the shop to show *any* products when I go that route. This must require a more complex WP query statement than I can figure out right now.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I thought it would be a straight forward toggle for visibility, not as complex as that.