# Hide single products from loop ONLY if part of grouped product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store with lots of grouped & simple products. I don't want the child products that are part of a group to show in archive loop. 
I can't use "hidden" attribute, because this causes the link to product page to disable from grouped product page.

This is the same issue I'm having: [Woocommerce - Only show grouped products parent in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975262/woocommerce-only-show-grouped-products-parent-in-the-loop)

I tried the follow code (from above link)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'only_grouped_products_query' );
function only_grouped_products_query( $q ) {

    //get current loop query
   $taxonomy_query = $q->get('tax_query') ;

   //appends the grouped products condition
   $taxonomy_query['relation'] = 'AND';
   $taxonomy_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => 'grouped'
   );


   $q->set( 'tax_query', $taxonomy_query );
}
```

This did half of what I need, but it hid ALL simple products, even if they aren't in a group.

Comment: Alternatively, I could mark them all as hidden if I could make the child products still have a link to the single product page.